# Stop Youtube from playing when Modal is closed

Tags: jquery, youtube, modal-dialog

I've seen a few questions similar, but unfortunately, none of the answers have fixed my issue exactly. I have multiple modals that have a different video iFrame in each one. I would like for the video to stop playing when the modal is closed. So far, I tried using jQuery to stop the video when the user closes the modal. It works, but for some reason, all of the videos get replaced with the first video listed in my code. It's weird. You can see it here: http://tiffanymackins.com/gentrification/   I'm not using Bootstrap or any framework. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a snippet of the code i'm using:

```
<a href="#modal-soulshine"><img id="soulshine-pin" class="pins" src="images/redPin.png"></a> 
    <div id="modal-soulshine" class="modal">
       <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close"> close </a>
            <h2> Soulshine Organics Farm: Jesse Leadbetter and Nicole Argento</h2>
            <span class="ss-info"> Moved to Belmont in 2009</span>
           <iframe id="player" width="450" height="253" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EpDEd9R005k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

           <p>....</p>
       </div>     
    </div>
```

And this is the jQuery to stop the video from playing.:

```
/*Function built to take on search for youtube video in modal*/
function ytplayer() {
    $('.modal iframe').attr("src", $(".modal iframe").attr(
        "src"));
}  
/*Function shuts down video when dismiss button is toggled*/
$('.close').click(function() {
    $('#player').stop(this);
    ytplayer();
});
```

Comment: If you're not using the Youtube API, you'd have to remove the video from the source attribute, as in `$('.modal iframe').attr("src", "");`

Comment: Hmm, that seemed to just get rid of the videos after i closed the modal.

Comment: Well, yes, wasn't that the point? The only way to stop a video in an iFrame you have no control over, is to change the source of the iFrame getting rid of the content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the point was to stop the video so it wouldn't play in the background when another modal and video was selected.

Comment: And unless you're using the Youtube API and have access to the videos, you can't do that.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to kill the video on modal close, but then to have it come back if the modal is called again? I have a similar situation solved with a `case switch` function

Comment: I am. The thing is, I have a total of 6 modals with 6 different videos.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
$( '#modal-soulshine').on( 'hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {

    $( '#modal-soulshineiframe' ).removeAttr( 'src' );

});
```